# node.js move bunch of files

Tags: node.js, file-upload

i have made a form for file upload and i have set the multiple option, so im trying to upload a bunch of files and then move them according to the album name that the client have set,
here is what iv done:

```
if (req.body && req.body.album){
        var album_name = req.body.album;
    }
    else{
        //need to change to time instead of random album
        var album_name = 'unknown_album-' + (parseInt(Math.random() * 5) + 1);
    }
    //File name
    var file_name = null;

    switch(req.files.img_file.type){
        case 'image/png':
            file_name = new Date().getTime() + '.png';
            break;
        case 'image/jpeg':
            file_name = new Date().getTime() + '.jpeg';
            break;
        default:
            res.render('admin/panel', {
                title: 'אדמין',
                message: 'קובץ לא תקין'
            });
            break;
    }

    mkdirp('./public/img/albums/' + album_name, function (err) {
        if (err) 
            console.error(err);
        else
        {
            _.each(req.files.img_file,function(val,index){
            console.log(val.path + " " + index);
//gives the file path so i can read it
                fs.readFile(val.path, function (err, data) {
                    if (err){
                        console.log("fs " + err);
                    }
//so until here everything works fine, the files are uploaded to the "/uploads" directory, now im trying to move them to the correct album, the destiation is : public/img/albums/:album_name/:all_images here
                    mv(val.path, './public/img/albums/' + album_name + '/' + val.path, function(err) {
                        if (err){
                            console.log("mv " + err);
                        }
                        else{
                            res.render('admin/panel', {
                                title: 'אדמין',
                                message: 'קובץ עלה בהצלחה'
                            });
                            res.redirect('/admin');
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

the mv module throws an error rename "c:/work/xxx/xx/uploads/val.path.png

Comment: `c:/work:/` doesn't look like a valid path to me.

Comment: My bad I wrote it incorrectly.  Its c:/work/....

Comment: Does the directory you're moving the file to exist already?

Comment: By mv module you mean you are using [this](https://npmjs.org/package/mv) library?

Comment: the directory is already exist, and yes i mean the mv module that youve linked to..

Answer (score 0):

Its a file-access error. You X out some of the file name, but look at how that NPM module handles file, and ensure you are naming the files and paths properly. Then it should work out fine.

Answer (score 0):

i have used read and write stream and deleted the "mv" module

```
if (req.body && req.body.album){
        var album_name = req.body.album;
    }
    else{
        //need to change to time instead of random album
        var album_name = 'unknown_album-' + (parseInt(Math.random() * 5) + 1);
    }

    //File name
   if (req.files.img_file.length > 1)
   {
    var Counter = 0;
        _.each(req.files.img_file,function(val,index){
            var file_name = null;
            switch(val.type){
                case 'image/png':
                    file_name = new Date().getTime() + '.png';
                    break;
                case 'image/jpeg':
                    file_name = new Date().getTime() + '.jpeg';
                    break;
            }

            mkdirp('./public/img/albums/' + album_name, function (err) {
                if (err) 
                    console.error(err);

                var source = fs.createReadStream(val.path);
                var dest = fs.createWriteStream('./public/img/albums/' + album_name + '/' + val.name);

                source.pipe(dest);
                source.on('end', function() {
                    console.log('end...');
                    Counter++;
                        console.log(Counter);
                        console.log(req.files.img_file.length);
                        if (Counter == req.files.img_file.length){
                            res.redirect('/admin');
                            res.render('admin/panel', {
                                title: 'אדמין',
                                message: 'קובץ עלה בהצלחה',
                                albums: albums
                            }); //eo res render     
                        }
                });
                source.on('error', function(err) { console.log('error'); });

            });// eo mkdir
        }); // eo _each
   }
```